# Showing the exact overlap area in Topology Checker QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, topology

I am using the Topology checker in QGIS 3.10.11 to find overlaps in a large polygon layer. How can you get it to show you exactly where the overlap is?

It just shows me there is an overlap somewhere on a huge polygon of over 300 ha with hundreds of nodes, cause finding it could take hours.

Comment: Can you please provide a graphical support of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Define `must not overlap` in the settings, then run the topology checker.
It will show you the overlapping areas highlighted in red. Click on one of the outputs (errors) to jump to the respective area. The errors are highlighted in red:

[image]